# Concatenating two tables with same column number and name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

TABLE_A

```
head1 head2
foo   case1
bar   case2
```

and TABLE_B

```
head1 head2
hux   case1
pix   case2
ilf   case1
```

What I want to do is to create this table:

```
head1 head2
foo case1
bar case2
hux case1
pix case2
ilf case3
```

Namely just combine them, without removing any redundancy.

What's the right command to do it?
I tried this but it didn't give the the desired result.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_AB(head1 text, head2 text)
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_A)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the parenthesis around the union parts.  Also, for `create table ... select`, you don't have the specify the column definitons.

```
create table Table3
select  *
from    Table1
union all
select  *
from    Table2
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4077b/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

You may change the columns names to the desired ones.

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 (ID number, NAME VARCHAR2(10));
CREATE TABLE TAB2 (ID number, NAME VARCHAR2(10));

INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (1, 'AAA');
INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (2, 'BBB');
INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (3, 'CCC');

INSERT INTO TAB2 VALUES (1, 'EEE');
INSERT INTO TAB2 VALUES (4, 'FFF');

CREATE TABLE TAB AS ((SELECT * FROM TAB1) UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM TAB2));
```